# LINQ Filtering - Optimization

Tags: c#, linq

I make one database trip to get a list of entities.
I then would like to separate this list into 2 lists, one for the entities that have not expired (using a start and end) which i call TopListings and another which are regular listings, those that have expired or have start/end date as null (the ones that are not TopListings)

I am not entirely sure which filtering is fasted to separate into 2 lists, should I get the toplist first, then filter second list based on what is NOT in the top list for second?

```
var listings = ListingAdapter.GetMapListings(criteria);

var topListings = listings.Where(x => x.TopStartDate >= DateTime.Now && x.TopExpireDate >= DateTime.Now);

//I AM NOT SURE WHAT THIS LINE SHOULD BE
var regularListings = listings.Where(x => x.TopStartDate < DateTime.Now || x.TopExpireDate < DateTime.Now || x.TopStartDate == null || x.TopExpireDate == null );
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it would probably be easier to use a loop, instead of Linq operators:

```
var topListings = new List<Listing>();
var regularListings = new List<Listing>();
foreach (var x in listings)
{
    if (x.TopStartDate >= DateTime.Now && x.TopExpireDate >= DateTime.Now)
        topListings.Add(x);
    else
        regularListings.Add(x);
}
```

This is also more efficient, because the list is enumerated only once.

Comment: I thought linq operators/filters generally were more efficient than loops?

Comment: @Zoinky, Linq is nominally slower than a standard for loop.  Just comes with the overhead of the language.

Comment: @Zoinky, there's no reason why Linq operators should be faster than loops... how do you think they're implemented ;) ? I suggest you check out Jon Skeet's series about [reimplementing Linq to Objects](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/09/03/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-1-introduction.aspx), it gives very interesting insight about the inner workings of Linq.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use a LookUp

like this:

```
var lookup = listings.ToLookup(x => x.TopStartDate >= DateTime.Now && x.TopExpireDate >= DateTime.Now);
var topListings = lookup[true];
var regularListings = lookup[false]; // I assume everything not a topListing is a regular listing.
```

If this isnt enough, you could create an enum

```
enum ListingType { Top, Regular, WhatEver };

...

var lookup = listings.ToLookUp(determineListingType); // pass a methoddelegate that determines the listingtype for an element.

...

var topListings = lookup[ListingType.Top];
var regularListings = lookup[ListingType.Regular];
var whateverListings = lookup[ListingType.WhatEver];
```

Comment: +1 for a creative use of `ToLookup`. I never found a really good way to partition lists, so I always resorted to loops. I'll keep this approach in mind next time ;)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the 'Except' operator to make things a little easier. You might have to add a .ToList() on topListings first though.

```
var regularListings = listings.Except(topListings);
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2008/07/12/the-linq-set-operators.aspx

Comment: This is probably what I am looking for, how efficient is it though compared to say a regular foreach loop?

Comment: @Zoinky This is not as "efficient" as Thomas Levesque answer since this needs to loop `listings` twice. (once to build `topListings` and once for `regularListings`)

Answer (score 1):

Make use of regular `foreach` loop that's straight forward. You can iterate through `listing` with one go and add items to appropriate collections. If you are LINQ kind of guy, `ForEach` extension is what you are looking for:

```
var topListings = new List<Listing>();
var regularListings = new List<Listing>();

listing.ForEach(item=>{
                      if (x.TopStartDate < DateTime.Now 
                            ||       // I've inverted the condition, since it is faster-one or two conditions will be checked, instead of always two
                          x.TopExpireDate < DateTime.Now)
                        regularListings.Add(x);
                      else
                        topListings.Add(x);
                });
```

Comment: "People have completely forgot the use of regular foreach loop", yet you suggest an implementation than doesn't use a foreach loop ;)

Comment: this is my edited answer. I didn't add any code because I thought it is obvious. Later you've answered in a similar way and added the code. OP asked me that I should have added the code as well(now we've removed our chatter under my answer). So. In order not to make my code a copy of your one, I've made it through ForEach extension.

Comment: no need to explain, I wasn't criticizing your answer... I was just pointing out the irony ;)

Comment: Should I have used the "straight forward" `foreach` you'd told me I've edited my answer using your code;)